# .htaccess file cannot be save in wordpress on live hostinger

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Below is our .htaccess file in my wordpress on live hostinger.
I am trying to update(make changes) this .htaccess file, but it could not be save or update, why this is happening please suggest me.

```bash
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: i am waiting for your valuable reply

Answer (score 0):

deactivate security plugins, Some plugins protect .htaccess file

Comment: Till yesterday it works fine, but suddenly find this issue...is any other solution, i don't have any security plugin.

Comment: i have list of plugin installed-->AccessPress Social Icons, Anything Popup, Easy Logo Slider, MCE Table Buttons, Meta Slider, Search Autocomplete, WPB Accordion Menu or Category